# Simple function to Http GET some data

Tags: android, kotlin, https

This is within a base class of a library, where several other classes inherit this one.

This seems like the simplest way of just getting some data, for now without timeout/errorhandling. This is supposed to get some data that will most ofthe time be converted to a small JSONObject.

Do you think I should put everything inside the `try` and use `val`? Any other suggestions? I'm basically just learning networking with android, only did it in C#.NET before.

```
protected fun sendGetRequest(url: URL): String {
    var urlConnection: HttpsURLConnection? = null
    var reader: InputStreamReader? = null
    var responseData = ""
    try {
        urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection

        reader = InputStreamReader(urlConnection.inputStream)
        responseData = reader.readText()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        this.messageHandler.handleMessage(e.message!!)
    }finally {
        reader?.close()
        urlConnection?.disconnect()
    }
    return responseData
}
```

Comment: But you _are_ doing error handling. What does `this.messageHandler` do?

Comment: It propagates messages to the outside of the library. Right now the app using it just shows the message in a toast. With error handling I mean actually handling http codes and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your code can be replaced by the following code:

```
url.openConnection()    //you can cast to fail if it isn't https
   .getInputStream()   //same as you
   .reader()          // same as wrapping it in inputStreamReader
   .use { it ->      // start lambda that handles the closing of the reader for you
      it.readText() // note, it's one parameter, so 'it ->' can be omitted
    }
```

The code above returns the text or throws the exception it got during execution, but always closes the reader, which in turn [closes the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956163/does-closing-the-inputstream-of-a-socket-also-close-the-socket-connection).

The code above is almost the same as the code below btw:

```
url.readText()
```

If you want to remove all the variables, you should know that try catch can return a value:

```
val a = try{ 1 } catch(e: Exception) { 2 }
```

Comment: So if I handle possible exceptions somewhere else, basically the whole thing I made is just `url.readText()`? That is quite simple. I'm glad I asked.

Comment: yup. 
[In the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.net.-u-r-l/read-text.html), Kotlin tells you not to use it for *huge* files. The reason is because the text will be stored into a String, so into memory. This means it can almost always be ignored.

Comment: In android you could theoretically store around  [4 million characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369204/3193776). Just a little bit more than the letters of the bible :-)

Comment: Oh I expect a small json object most of the time, and an error page or nothing on error. Thanks for the help :D